Easy way to administrate (add and remove) OpenIddict clients?
I'm using the latest version (5.6.0) of the NuGet package OpenIddict in an ASP.NET Core project with .NET 8. They have an example on https://documentation.openiddict.com/guides/getting-started/creating-your-own-server-instance.html showing how to register a new client with an ID and secret:
var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOpenIddictApplicationManager>();
if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("service-worker") is null)
{
    await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
    {
        ClientId = "service-worker",
        ClientSecret = "388D45FA-B36B-4988-BA59-B187D329C207",
        Permissions =
        {
            Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
            Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials
        }
    });
}

I have seen that the client gets saved to the database table OpenIddictApplication:

My question is:

Is there any easy way to administrate the clients without having to modify any code? E.g. if I want to add or delete a client, I would like to be able to do that without having to deploy a new version of the application. Is there anything built-in in OpenIddict that already solves this?


In my experience openiddict doesn't have good support for this, maybe there is some 3rd party management UI but it is hard to guarantee the quility. 
Generally internet provider will offer this function, such as "Azure entra Id" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/architecture/auth-oauth2 
If you only want local provider, I suggest you use "KeyCloak". Despite it is not developed by c#, as we only need the endpoint so we needn't care about the codes. Most importantly, it has a really nice management UI for you to setup almost anything you need. https://www.keycloak.org/



Is there any easy way to administrate the clients without having to modify any code? E.g. if I want to add or delete a client, I would like to be able to do that without having to deploy a new version of the application. Is there anything built-in in OpenIddict that already solves this?

OpenIddict doesn't force you to have the application management logic in the same application as your OpenID Connect server so nothing prevents you from having a separate application/script/function that takes care of that.
Here's a sample setting up a DI container and updating the properties of an existing application using the IOpenIddictApplicationManager service:
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using OpenIddict.Abstractions;
using OpenIddict.MongoDb;
using OpenIddict.MongoDb.Models;

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options => options.UseMongoDb());

services.AddSingleton(new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017").GetDatabase("openiddict"));

await using var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var manager = provider.GetRequiredService<IOpenIddictApplicationManager>();

var application = await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("myapp") ??
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The client doesn't exist.");

var descriptor = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor();
await manager.PopulateAsync(descriptor, application);

descriptor.DisplayName = "My application";
descriptor.DisplayNames[CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR")] = "Mon application";

await manager.UpdateAsync(application, descriptor);

Alternatively, if you prefer a graphical approach, there are third-party projects you can use:

OpenIddict UI by Thomas Duft.
OrchardCore OpenID module (see https://kevinchalet.com/2020/10/03/using-the-orchardcore-openid-management-feature-with-an-existing-openiddict-deployment/)
pixel-identity by Nishant Singh.

And of course, if you prefer a REST API, you can easily build one using the APIs offered by IOpenIddictApplicationManager (or you can use https://github.com/SharpGrip/OpenIddict.Api as a starting point)
